# Plotly Chart Size Changing When Hiding and Showing Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, button, plotly

I have a Plotly plot that needs to be hidden when the page loads and then be shown when a button is pressed.

I tried to do so by setting the div that the plot goes inside as display = none & changing to
display = block when the button is pressed.

This however ruins the sizing of the plot and it exceeds the dimensions of the div that it is in. Is there a reason for this?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

    <script src="https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <div id="plot" style="width:40%; margin: auto; border: 2px solid black; display: none;"> 
    </div>

    <script>

        var xArray = [];
        var yArray = [];

        for (let i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            xArray.push(i);
            yArray.push(Math.floor(Math.random()*100));
        }

        var data = [{x: xArray,y: yArray,mode:"lines"}];

        var layout = {xaxis: {range: [0, 19], title: "Hour"}, yaxis: {range: [0, 99], title: 
                 "Share Price ($)"}, title: "ACME Inc"};

        Plotly.newPlot("plot", data, layout);
        
    </script>

    <script>

    function HideDiv() {

        document.getElementById('plot').style.display = "none";
    }

    function ShowDiv() {

        document.getElementById('plot').style.display = "block";
    }

    </script>

    <div style="text-align: center; position: fixed; left: 45%; bottom: 50%;">
        <br/>
        <button style="text-align: center;" onclick="HideDiv()">Hide Plot</button>
        <button style="text-align: center;" onclick="ShowDiv()">Show Plot</button>
        
    </div>


</body>

</html>
```